# webpack-intergrity-subresource don't make any effect

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, subresource-integrity

I'm trying to apply the plugin to my nuxtjs's webpack to enable `subresource integrity`. Here is my nuxt.config.js

```js
 extend(config) {
      config.output!.crossOriginLoading = "anonymous";
    },
    plugins: [
      new SriPlugin({
        hashFuncNames: ["sha256", "sha512"],
      }),
    ],
```

no error is emitted, but when I view the DOM, the script tag didn't change. I expected the script tag to look like this, since the webpack plugin already running.

```html
<script src="/_nuxt/app.js" integrity="sha256-QcoWoREdQOlM2GAA/i4qmOYRMED/cckK1XPNKTCVh9g= sha512-S163FQo9fj70zvaK4IouYKyk2O2jyKGNimr/z6SJD6xHeN7p4sQOS979HKwDhpXTS7OUegEleaP1q/K6qjVjxw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I tried to debug and logging in the package's source code but nothing go wrong. In both `webpack-intergrity-subresource` and `html-webpack-plugin`, the script tag looked as my expect, but when they came to browser, they looked different

my versions:

```json
"nuxt": "^2.15.8", ("@nuxt/webpack": "2.15.8")
"webpack-subresource-integrity": "1.5.2"
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, *it's not working* is a totally useless problem description. Please [edit] your post to remove the unnecessary image and replace it with text, and to provide a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nuxtjs only use html-webpack-plugin to inject resource in `Static Site Generation`, for ssr they do it themself. So basically we can only enable subresource integrity when in static mode.

[nuxt's ssr renderer](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/00c3b95ab36d6d72c3f2737a3d0cc821228eddb5/packages/vue-renderer/src/renderers/ssr.js#L199)